# how to create a variant for configurable products in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

how to create a variant for configurable products in magento 1.9[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem like default Magento. Are you using any third party module?

Comment: i wanted to create this module

Comment: Can you please add code for your module to the question?